# Trying to find a way to check if a System::String variable can be parsed into double in C++

Tags: type-conversion, c++-cli

I have a seemingly simple but maddening problem.

I normally work in either MATLAB or Python, but I wanted to create a relatively small sized stand alone code the runs some safety calculations from a GUI.  The program reads user inputs from textboxes, carries out the relevant calculations and revises the GUI with those calculations.

The GUI itself was created as a Windows form in C++.  I read data form the textboxes using the System::Convert::ToDouble method from the Windows namespace.  A problem occurs if a textbox entry cannot be parsed into a double, at which point ToDouble immediately crashes to desktop.  So I want a way to check if the user inputs can be parsed into double variables before running System::Convert::ToDouble, and I cannot for the life of my figure out a way to do this that actually works.

I can't seem to use the System::Convert::ToDouble itself because it seems to crash to desktop rather than produce a specific kind of error state output I could use to have the program handle a failure state.

I can't use any documented C++ methods to check for the parsing because those are relevant to std::string variables and these textboxes return System::String variables which work differently.

I can't seem to use methods specific to this System::String class because all the documented methods I can find, such as MyParse, seem to work for C sharp but not C++.

I can't convert from System::String to std::string because all the documented methods for doing so require msclr\marshal_cppstd.h, and simply including this header creates a dozen IServiceProvider errors I don't have the first clue on how to correct.

This simple problem has brought my programming project to a halt.  Does anyone know how I can go about solving it?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todouble?view=net-6.0#system-convert-todouble\(system-string\)), looks like it throws an exception if the parsing fails.  Are you `catch`ing this exception?

Comment: You might also try [`Double::TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=net-6.0).

Comment: "from the Windows namespace" -> no, it is in the `System` namespace, in the `Convert` class, hence the name `System::Convert::ToDouble()`.  You probably meant to say "in the .NET Base Class Library".  Your project is using the .NET Base Class Library aka BCL and the .NET Windows Forms library aka WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

0x5453 has already steered you in the direction of the right function in a comment, but I wanted to provide you an example as most of what you will find online are C# examples.

```
System::String^ its_a_string = textBox1->Text;
double numeric_value;
if (System::Double::TryParse(its_a_string, numeric_value)) {
    // conversion success, you can use numeric_value
    // you don't need to call System::Convert::ToDouble()
    // since TryParse did both the test can-it-be-converted? and also the conversion
}
else {
    // conversion failed, numeric_value will be 0.0
}
```

Note that the byref output parameters is not annotated with `out` as it would be in C# or `&` as it would be in C.  C++ references are transparent at the call-site (which is very good for operands to overloaded operators, and pretty bad otherwise) and this applies to C++/CLI support for .NET tracking references also.